# operator++ in a forward iterator for Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-search-tree, inorder, const-iterator

I'm trying to implement an increment operator (operator++) to iterate a BST (in-order traversal) but I got a problem any time I try to go to the Parent node. This is how I defined the node struct [It's a **class Template** ].

```
struct node{
    T value;  //Template    
    node *left;     //pointer to the left child 
    node *right;    /pointer to the right child 

    node() : left(0) , right(0) {} 

    node(const T &v, node *l = 0 , node *r = 0)
        : value(v), left(l) , right(r) {}
}; node * _root;
```

the iterator begins from the smallest child in the left

```
const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(FindSmallestPrivate(_root));}
```

and it ends when it points null

```
const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator(0);}
```

part of class const_iterator

```
class const_iterator {

     const node *n;

public:
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef T                         value_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t                 difference_type;
    typedef const T*                  pointer;
    typedef const T&                  reference;


    const_iterator() : n(0)){
    }

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &other) : n(other.n){

    }


    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator &other) {
        n = other.n;
        return *this;
    }

~const_iterator() {
        n = 0;
    }
```

now the main problem I still can't solve is here :

```
const_iterator operator++(int) {
    const_iterator tmp(*this);

  /**
   starting from the smallest key and base on a given case
   it should points to the next smallest key (successor)
   and so on until it finds there are no more keys in the tree.

    */

    return *this;
    }
```

I tried many ways to find a solution using helper functions in the iterator class but still even calling a function that finds the successor of a given node that works pretty fine in BST class STILL THE SAME PROBLEM.
when I try to pass "n" to the function that finds its successor I get an error at compile time : "cannot call member function without object".

if anyone knows a way to solve this problem , please let me know.

Comment: "when I try to pass "n" "? What is "n"? There's nothing in the shown code that's called "n". "I'd be happy to post source for the entire class" -- no, don't do that. You need to post a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. Did you read yet stackoverflow.com's [help], that explains how to ask questions, and if not, why not?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for replying. I just edited the post adding more details.

Comment: You will have a really, really tough time without an explicit `parent` pointer in each node.

Comment: @n.m. ahaha! I've already knew that :D .I think if I modify the struct adding the parent node it would be much easier but I wrote here to see if there is any possible way to do it.

Comment: Your iterator class can always maintain an internal state of all nodes from the root down to the current node the iterator is referencing and, as such, be able to navigate the tree without formally storing the parent in each node.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Such an iterator would be large and expensive to copy. Iterators are not meant to be such beasts. Moreover, tree modifications would invalidate such iterators.

Comment: @n.m. Well, parent node information must be stored *somewhere* - if not in each node, then there's no other choice but to store it in the iterator. There is, of course, a performance trade-off the author should consider. As to invalidation - `std::vector` modifications also tend to invalidate all iterators, and yet `std::vector` is widely used. Such invalidation, in itself, is clearly not a fatal flaw.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the tradeoff is extremely easy. Have the parent pointer in each node *once*, or have the entire path in *every* iterator that needs to be copied with every iteratir copy and updated with every iterator advance *and* have them invalidated at every tree modification. Do you prefer $1000 or a bedbug infestation? The choice is rather clear.

Comment: @n.m. Perhaps storage costs are prohibitive. Storing parent pointer in each node takes `O(n)` extra memory, while storing the path in the iterator takes `O(log n)` for a reasonably balanced tree. Perhaps the access pattern is such that there's only one traversal - one copy of the iterator - outstanding at any given time, and guaranteed not to interleave with tree modification. Or perhaps the OP was simply asked, as a learning assignment, to find a way to manage without back-pointers in the nodes. In other words, there could be reasons to choose one approach over the other, in either direction.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If storage costs are prohibitive, you may want to avoid pointer-based trees altogether. But hey, whatever works.